# How to push changes on heroku using git(using http)

Tags: reactjs, git, heroku

I have made a react app and deployed that on Heroku using git( using https). Now I have made some changes in that react app. I am able to push my changes in the git but I am not able to push those changes to Heroku. I used this command

```
git push heroku master
```

The error which I am getting is:

```
git@heroku.com: Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to upload your public key to Heroku:

```
heroku keys:add ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

If you don't have a public key, Heroku will prompt you to add one automatically which works seamlessly. Just use:

```
heroku keys:add
```

To clear all your previous keys do :

```
heroku keys:clear
```

To display all your existing keys do :

```
heroku keys
```